# Centos & - httpd startup failure after yum update

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, centos7

I ran a yum update after which HTTP Apache server fails to start up on my Centos 7 VM.

The apache details - `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16`

Kernel version - `3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64`

Here is what the `systemctl` shows. I'm not able to figure out what is broken after the update.

```
[root@localhost log]# systemctl status httpd.service 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-02-26 16:32:37 NZDT; 4min 19s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 3654 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/kdestroy -A (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3651 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3649 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3574 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/ipa/ipa-httpd-kdcproxy (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3649 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain ipa-httpd-kdcproxy[3574]: ipa         : WARNING  Disabling KDC proxy
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: [Fri Feb 26 16:32:37.213684 2016] [so:warn] [pid 3649] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: [Fri Feb 26 16:32:37.217181 2016] [so:warn] [pid 3649] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain httpd[3649]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directi... this message
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain kill[3651]: kill: cannot find process ""
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 16:32:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Could I please request help to get some pointers to dig further or anyone who has seen this before & knows how to fix please?

**ERROR LOG**

```
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.053349 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1415] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.061849 2016] [so:warn] [pid 1415] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.065365 2016] [so:warn] [pid 1415] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.074575 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1415] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.076265 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1415] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Mar 27 11:36:01.127763 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1421] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 27 11:36:01.127774 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1421] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.053349 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1415] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.061849 2016] [so:warn] [pid 1415] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.065365 2016] [so:warn] [pid 1415] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.074575 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1415] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.076265 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1415] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'dom' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'wddx' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlreader' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlwriter' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.205371 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1415] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 28 20:05:24.205404 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1415] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Mar 28 20:12:40.996976 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:12:51.008348 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:01.051766 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:11.065419 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:21.077136 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:31.091594 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:41.102475 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:13:51.118069 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:01.127042 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:11.241544 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:21.307679 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:31.320048 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:41.339734 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:14:51.419001 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:01.602720 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:11.649031 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:21.666765 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:31.682282 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:41.699731 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:15:51.741056 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:01.753341 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:11.765981 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:21.778842 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:31.795109 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:41.810008 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:16:51.822934 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:01.836868 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:11.851730 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:21.867661 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:31.881686 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:41.894839 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:17:51.908915 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:01.922930 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:11.937345 2016] [:error] [pid 1415] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:13.001146 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1415] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:16.197266 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 34136] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:16.197294 2016] [:warn] [pid 34136] NSSSessionCacheTimeout is deprecated. Ignoring.
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:16.216828 2016] [:error] [pid 34136] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Mon Mar 28 20:18:16.216850 2016] [:error] [pid 34136] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[Mon Mar 28 20:25:59.205718 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 47010] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 28 20:25:59.205743 2016] [:warn] [pid 47010] NSSSessionCacheTimeout is deprecated. Ignoring.
[Mon Mar 28 20:25:59.227850 2016] [:error] [pid 47010] NSS_Initialize failed. Certificate database: /etc/httpd/alias.
[Mon Mar 28 20:25:59.227871 2016] [:error] [pid 47010] SSL Library Error: -8038 SEC_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

**journal -xe**
This command shows hundreds of lines of the below message

```
Mar 28 20:33:31 localhost.localdomain pulseaudio[2055]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Failed to set software parameters: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please provide the apache/httpd logs in `/var/log/httpd/` directory so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: use apachectl -t (for testing the configs), that usually gives useful hints as to where the configuration errors are

Comment: Hello - Sorry for the delay in coming back. I did not have time to retry. I upgraded another VM of Centos& & can replicate the problem. I've updated the question with `error logs` & output from `journal -xe` command. Looks like a bunch of permission errors but don't know what these are. I have disabled SE linux mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check the /var/log/httpd logs and if not check the "yum update" again.then restart the httpd service .check /var/log/messages and /var/log/httpd  and yum log.So, you can identify the issue.

Comment: The file you're interested in is /var/log/httpd/error_log - this is where you'll see the error preventing Apache to start.

Comment: Hello - Sorry for the delay in coming back. I did not have time to retry. I upgraded another VM of Centos& & can replicate the problem. I've updated the question with `error logs` & output from `journal -xe` command. Looks like a bunch of permission errors but don't know what these are. I have disabled SE linux mode.